# How to batch more than 500 operations in python for firestore?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating documents from web scraping in python and uploading them to Firestore.
To do so I'm adding them to a dictionary and uploading them from a for loop in python, one by one(ideally would be better to upload the collection at once, but that doesn't seem an option). I want to use batches, however they have the 500 limit per batch and I need to do more than 100,000 operations. The operations are merely `set()` operations and a couple of `update()`
Is there a function to know the current size of the batch so I can reinitialize it?
What is the best way to use batches for more than 500 operations in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way I found to deal with the 500 batch limit, while working with python, is to put all my data I want to send to Firestore in a 'Flat' dictionary so I can work with every unique document. This dictionary has as key for every document the form of: 'collection_document_collection_document...' while the value for that key would be a dictionary with:

```
{'action': 'set', 'reference': reference, 'document': {}}
```

The 'action' can be 'set', 'update' or 'delete', the 'reference' key is an actual Firestore reference, and the 'document' is just the document.
For instance this are 2 documents in different locations.

```
{
    'user_data_roger':
    {'action': 'set', 'reference': db.collection('user_data').document('roger'), 'document': {'name': 'Roger', 'age': 37}},
    'user_data_roger_works_april':
    {'action': 'update', 'reference': db.collection('user_data').document('roger').collection('works').document('april'), 'document': {'is_valid': True, 'in_progress': True, 'level':5}},
}
```

After processing all the data I need I want to split the dictionary in arrays of 500 items and then add all of those Items to the batch, using the 'action' key for the batch.

```
# Convert dictionary to a list
dictionary_list = []
for item in dictionary:
    dictionary_list.append(dictionary.get(item))
# Split List in lists containing 500 items per list
list_to_batch = [dictionary_list[item:item+500] for item in range(0, len(dictionary_list), 500)]
# Finally iterate through the 'list_to_batch' add each item to the batch and commit using a for loop
for item in list_to_batch:
    batch = db.batch()
    for document in item:
        if document['action'] == 'set':
            batch.set(document['reference'], document['value'])
        elif draw['action'] == 'update':
            batch.update(document['reference'], document['value'])
        else:
            batch.delete(document['reference'], document['value'])
    # Finally commit the batch
    batch.commit()
```

In my particular case after processing all the data I needed, I ended up with more than 700,000 operations, so watch out for the billing :-D

Answer (score 4):

The maximum number of operations in a Batch is 500. If you need more operations, you'll need multiple batches.

There is no API to determine the current number of operations in a Batch. If you need that, you will have to track it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can not exceed the 500 operations limit, but you have some simple ways to split your operations into small batches.

Let's say you need to update every document in a collection. This works:

```
collection_ref = firestore_client.collection(col)

batch = firestore_client.batch()

for i, doc in enumerate(collection_ref.list_documents()):
    if i % 500 == 499:
        batch.commit()
        batch = firestore_client.batch()
    batch.update(doc, {"some field": "some value"})

batch.commit()
```